# How to adjust the branch length of dendrogram converted from Newick file?

Tags: r

Hi I aim to make a heat map of species abundance and also show phylogeny tree in parallel. The phylogeny tree was made in MEGA and input to R as Newick file prior to converting to dendrogram object.

However, the branch length of phylogeny tree in the output figure was not the same length. Can I ask is there any way to make the branch length similar?

I attached the code and the output below. Thank you in advance.

```
library(DECIPHER)
library(dendextend)
library(ape)

#Input the tree from newick file from Mega and convert into dendrogram
dend <- ReadDendrogram("VPstrainand3-major_ASV_5%_withlength.nwk")

#Make the plot using data from the excel stored in the directory
#load the data
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
heatmap.dataframe <- read.xlsx("Complete.xlsx","Modified", rowNames =TRUE)
heatmap.mat <- as.matrix(heatmap.dataframe)
whitered <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"), space = "rgb")(100)

#plot
library(repr)
options (repr.plot.width=20, repr.plot.height=20)
heatmap <- heatmap(as.matrix(heatmap.mat), Rowv = dend, Colv = NA, col = whitered)
print(heatmap)
```

[Output heat map with phylogeny tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkbK6.png)

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:git]? (I think you may have accepted a machine-suggestion based on the word "branch", but Git's branches have nothing to do with phylogeny branches. Please check and correct your tags.)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a combination of `dendrapply()` and a simple function - named `ForceUltrametric` in this example. This form can be used for a couple different tasks, the example present in `dendrapply`'s help file is for changing leaf colors, but you could use this for adding points below leaves, or adjusting labels as well.

A reproducible example of your entire process in R, since we don't have access to your newick file:

```
library(DECIPHER)

# using one of DECIPHER's built in examples:
db <- system.file("extdata",
                  "Bacteria_175seqs.sqlite",
                  package="DECIPHER")
dna <- SearchDB(db,
                remove="all")
alignedDNA <- AlignSeqs(dna)

Dist <- DistanceMatrix(myXStringSet = alignedDNA,
                       includeTerminalGaps = TRUE, # global identity
                       verbose = TRUE)
tree1 <- IdClusters(myDistMatrix = Dist,
                    method = "NJ", # a non-ultrametric tree
                    verbose = TRUE,
                    showPlot = FALSE, # you can return a plot as the function completes, or not
                    type = "dendrogram") # return a dendrogram

ForceUltrametric <- function(n) {
  if (is.leaf(n)) {
    # if object is a leaf, adjust height attribute
    attr(n, "height") <- 0L
  }
  return(n)
}

tree2 <- dendrapply(X = tree1,
                    FUN = function(x) ForceUltrametric(x))
```

Using some newick file, which we don't have access to, and cannot guarantee working:

```
library(DECIPHER)

tree1 <- ReadDendrogram("<yourfilehere>")

ForceUltrametric <- function(n) {
  if (is.leaf(n)) {
    # if object is a leaf, adjust height attribute
    attr(n, "height") <- 0L
  }
  return(n)
}

tree2 <- dendrapply(X = tree1,
                    FUN = function(x) ForceUltrametric(x))
```

It should be noted that while it's pleasant to force dendrograms to be ultrametric in cases where you want to plot data below the leaves, it isn't really an accurate representation of the data if the tree was built with a non-ultrametric method.

tree1[image: Original Tree]

tree2[image: Forced Ultrametric Tree]